# Horror/SFF anthology about fat/overweight characters

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

(It wasn't particularly body-positive, let's just say, but I am looking for it anyway).

Anthology. I thought it was pretty mainstream, like Datlow or Greenberg or Dozois, but no matter how I search I cannot find it. It was not super-old, but not published in the last couple of years either. I don't think that it was small press.

Stories included, I think, one about a girl in hospital for anorexia who turns the tables on her family/captors, one about an immobilized woman who is rescued at the end by an EMT or firefighter, one where a group of spacers are captive and fed high-calorie, addictive food that only one of them realizes is intended to fatten them up.

Comment: So this was a "theme" anthology?

Comment: Exactly, Spencer, but all my searches on Amazon, Goodreads, etc. have been fruitless.

Comment: Some Googling gave me [this](http://crossedgenres.com/titles/out-of-print-titles/fat-girl-in-a-strange-land/).

Comment: It isn't that one, but the colleague who wants the other one may be interested in that too. Thanks

Comment: Took me a bit to find the one I was thinking of...[Such a Pretty Face](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/888551.Such_a_Pretty_Face), edited by Lee Martindale. I don't know if it's the one you're looking for.

Comment: It's not Such a Pretty Face. it was much more horror-themed. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this question elsewhere via an intermediary and suggested two anthologies at that point:  [The Science Fiction Weight Loss Book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1793432.The_Science_Fiction_Weight_Loss_Book) ed. Asimov et al (1983) or [Fat](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?34965) ed. Kit Reed (1974).

I think the latter is mostly mainstream fiction, but with some sf/f included (and Reed of course had sf/f credentials, among other things).

I haven't read either anthology myself so do not know if any stories therein match the plot points noted.

Comment: Seeing as you're not sure if either of these are correct could you [edit] to say where you saw these suggestions? If it's only could you add a link in?

Comment: Searching google books for '"the food farm" kit reed' finds a match in the anthology "Weird Women, Wired Women"; the text is viewable there.  The (overweight) protagonist is sent to a facility by her parents to lose weight and in the end gets her revenge on them by imprisoning them and forcing them to gain all the weight she lost and can not regain.  I don't know if that matches what the OP is looking for or not.

Comment: Note that the ISFDB entry for "Fat" only lists 3 of the 20 stories/essays in the collection:  [library entry for Fat](https://trove.nla.gov.au/work/21830420?q&versionId=26273865)